# One MS SQL server returns wrong order for a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, doctrine-orm

We have multiple MSSQL servers that has the same copy of a database, the below query returns valid order for all servers except one, I double checked the design of the tables and all looks identical except couple of servers are missing an index.

The query is generated by doctrine

```
WITH dctrn_cte AS (
   SELECT TOP 10 a0_.Priority 
   FROM PROJECTS a0_ 
   WHERE a0_.ProjectID = 1234 
     AND (a0_.Check1 > 0 
          OR 
          a0_.Check2 > 0) 
     AND a0_.Active = 1 
   ORDER BY a0_.Priority DESC) 
   SELECT * 
   FROM (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS doctrine_rownum FROM dctrn_cte
      ) AS doctrine_tbl 
   WHERE doctrine_rownum BETWEEN 1 AND 10 ORDER BY doctrine_rownum ASC
```

Every time the query is executed on that particular server, it gives a random order - it is completely ignoring the ORDER BY part.

Comment: Which `order by’? The only one out of the three that is meaningful is the first one to pick the 10 rows. As the one used in the row numbering and thus in the final order by is completely undeterministic and doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: Why did you use `SELECT 0`?   What did you think would happen?

Answer (score 6):

your query has one final `ORDER BY` clause: `doctrine_rownum`. This is an alias for a column that is an undetermined value:

```
ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS doctrine_rownum
```

Therefore any order of the result is a correct order. All your servers return the correct result. [Select isn't broken](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/).

PS. You also have an `ORDER BY` inside the CTE, that is irrelevant to the final order, as it does not impose any order on the final result nor on the `doctrine_rownum` value.

> The query is generated by doctrine

The query is generated **incorrectly** by doctrine, whatever this doctrine is.

Comment: The `Order by` in the CTE does determine which 10 rows get selected by the CTE, so it's not completely irrelevant to the final results.   Though it is irrelevant to the order of those results.

Comment: Thanks Remus & Tab - The posted query is a very simplified version - we use [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)  to build dynamic queries and the CTE part is provided by it. I will investigate the used bundle and see if I can improve it.

Answer (score -2):

Adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` fixed the order on that server.

Comment: There is a difference between "fixing" and changing something so that the unreliable mechanism you are using is affected and subsequently tends to match what you want.  Fixing this would be understanding why it is not deterministic now and changing your database code so it is deterministic.

Comment: You are absolutely right - we were looking for a quick way to temporary 'fix' the issue without interrupting/delaying the deployment especially ordering is  a high priority requirement. Thanks.